# add a php variable to a css statement!

Tags: php, css

I would like to include the following in my css style statment. is it possible?

```
<option selected value="" class="" style= background: url<?php some php variable; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that portion of HTML code is in a `.php` file, yes, it is possible : PHP does just generate the output, no matter if the textual data is actually corresponding to CSS, HTML, JS, ...

Note though that your HTML code, here, is not quite OK : you are missing quotes arround the content of the `style` attribute, you should add parenthesis arround the url, and should use `selected="selected"`.

Also note that you need to `echo` the content of the variable -- and not just use its name.

So, basically, you should have something like this :

```
<option selected="selected" value="" class="" 
    style="background: url(<?php echo $your_variable; ?>)">
  text of your option
</option>
```

Comment: If you have `short_open_tag = true`, or if you use PHP 5.4.0 or later you can also use the short form. Ie. `url(<?= $your_variable ?>)`

Comment: it's working thanks. It looks as it follows    <?php foreach($list as $language):?>
 
     <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $language->active;?><?php echo $language->link;?>" class="css-avatar" 
     style="background: url(<?php if ($params->get('image', 1)):?><?php echo JRoute::_('media/mod_languages/images/'.$language->image.'.gif'); ?><?php endif;?>)">
         
    <?php echo $language->title?></option>

    <?php endforeach;?>

Answer (score 2):

Martin's answer is just fine, but I felt I should I point out that they way you are mixing CSS into the HTML isnt a good idea. Keeping the CSS part out of HTML file is always a better suggestion.

In case you would like the stylesheet to be generated for each request depending on certain values, (for eg, you need to pull values from the database), you could simply have a CSS file, and inside PHP tags you could pull the data and put it in the right place, like you would do for HTML.

For eg:

In HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php?user=abc" />
```

Style.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
$var = /*Get the background color setting for user abc*/;
?> 
.wrap{
    background-color:<?php echo $var; ?>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what PHP was born for

Try `echo $var;`